# How to parse JSON manually in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I want to parse JSON response manually in Kotlin. Since I am getting complex JSON response which is having some common fields. For example I am getting below response.

```
{ 
  status: "success/false"
  apiId: 6
  message: "Error msg if any"
  .
  .   
  .    // Here comes some JSON with complex structure where some fields are
  .    // missing/omitted. Sometime array is missing/response in array is
  .    // getting changed, getting lot of unwanted stuff Or whatever you can
  .    // think. And because of this I need to parse it manually.
  .
}
```

Now how can I parse this type of response manually in `data` class of Kotlin? One more thing I would like to know, can I use any base class for common fields in the response?

Comment: Isn't it the same as with the regular JSON object? jsonobj.getString(""), jsonobj.getObject("") ?

Comment: @user1940676 When you are using 'data' class in Kotlin you just need to define your variables in constructor only. You don't need to write getter() and setter()

Comment: Yea but can you try creating a JsonObject instance with the returned String and then call the methods of the JsonObject class to parse the data?

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
data class Response(val status: String, val apiId: Int , val message: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

[jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-inclusion) has `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` annotation which can ignore unwanted json fields. then what you need to do is write a data class like below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
data class Response(val status: String, val apiId: Int, val message: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [code in googlemaps repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-ktx/blob/9fe24161df688425d756eaae0c8fb14c3fd5b99a/app/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/ktx/demo/io/MyItemReader.kt) that provides manually parsing JSON object without 3rd party libraries. It parses JSON coordinates and seems pretty workable. The example of input JSON and code below:

```
[{"lat" : 51.5145160, "lng" : -0.1270060 },
{ "lat" : 51.5064490, "lng" : -0.1244260, "title" : "Corinthia Hotel London", "snippet": "Whitehall Pl"},
{ "lat" : 51.5097080, "lng" : -0.1200450,  "title" : "Savoy Place", "snippet" : "Covent Garden"},
{ "lat" : 51.5090680, "lng" : -0.1421420, "title" : "Albemarle St", "snippet": "Mayfair"},
{ "lat" : 51.4976080, "lng" : -0.1456320, "title" : " Victoria Square", "snippet": " Belgravia" },
{ "lat" : 51.5046150, "lng" : -0.1473780}]

 /**
 * Returns a list of cluster items read from the provided [inputStream]
 */
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun read(inputStream: InputStream): List<MyItem> {
    // This matches only once in whole input so Scanner.next returns whole InputStream as a
    // String. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/2183804
    val REGEX_INPUT_BOUNDARY_BEGINNING = "\\A"

    val items = mutableListOf<MyItem>()
    val json = Scanner(inputStream)
        .useDelimiter(REGEX_INPUT_BOUNDARY_BEGINNING).next()
    val array = JSONArray(json)
    for (i in 0 until array.length()) {
        var title: String? = null
        var snippet: String? = null
        val `object` = array.getJSONObject(i)
        val lat = `object`.getDouble("lat")
        val lng = `object`.getDouble("lng")
        if (!`object`.isNull("title")) {
            title = `object`.getString("title")
        }
        if (!`object`.isNull("snippet")) {
            snippet = `object`.getString("snippet")
        }
        items.add(MyItem(LatLng(lat, lng), title, snippet))
    }
    return items
}
```

And the final item is:

```
data class MyItem(val latLng: LatLng, val myTitle: String?, val mySnippet: String?) : ClusterItem
```